# How to use loop for like or ilike function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, sql-like

I am currently asked to validate the result of a global search which to find all records containing some keywords cross whole database. To do so, I need to check all the rows in each table that have keywords. The result for this global search is ready and partially of the result looks like the one below:

| table_name | column_name | keyword | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wf_Process | Name_EN | FEC | 11 |
| Wf_Process | FTABLENAME | GB | 14 |
| ICCClass | Name_EN | GB | 4 |

What I am trying to do is using the 'like' operator to extract all the data in each table where columns containing keywords. That is, I will use query such as:

```
select distinct Name_EN, FTABLENAME from Wf_Process where Name_EN like '%FEC%' or FTABLENAME like '%GB%'
```

and

```
select distinct Name_EN from ICCClass where Name_EN like '%GB%'
```

to pull out all data I need in whole database. If I only have three records, then it is not a problem. However my result returned over thousands tables have more than 10K rows containing keywords in total. Therefore, I was trying to use a loop to do this mission but I failed.

My question therefore is, does anyone have any idea to write a loop to do the 'like' search for all the tables in one time? Or is there another way rather than loop can do this in SQL Server?

Thank you very much!

Comment: freetext search?

Comment: @MitchWheat, I already found all tables which contains keywords in their columns, and I know which keywords these tables have. Yet, I just need to pull of such rows out. So freetext search may not very useful for given case.

Comment: Can you have multiple keywords for the same column, or only one per column (and multiple columns per table)?

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic SQL for this. You can generate a big `UNION ALL` query of all the tables together.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT
  ' + QUOTENAME(con.table_name, '''') + ' table_name,
  ' + QUOTENAME(con.column_name, '''') + ' column_name,
  ' + QUOTENAME(con.keyword, '''') + ' keyword,
  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ' t
WHERE t.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' LIKE ' + QUOTENAME('%' + con.keyword + '%', '''')

       AS nvarchar(max)), '
UNION ALL')

    FROM YourConditions con
    JOIN sys.tables t ON t.table_name
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE t.name = con.table_name
      AND c.name = con.column_name  
);

PRINT @sql;    -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

There are more efficient ways to do this if there are many columns or keywords per table, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The question looks odd, thou can be done via dynamic sql, but not as a regular solution more like a one off or POC/test.

```
use tempdb
GO

drop table if exists search_result
go

create table search_result (
table_name sysname
,column_name sysname 
,keyword varchar(100))
go

insert into search_result values
('Wf_Process', 'Name_EN', 'FEC')
,('Wf_Process' , 'FTABLENAME', 'GB')
,('ICCClass', 'Name_EN', 'GB')
GO

drop table if exists result 
create table result (val varchar(500))
go

declare @col sysname
declare @tab sysname
declare @kw varchar(100)
declare @sql varchar(1000)

while exists (select * from search_result)
begin
    select top 1
        @tab = table_name
        , @col = column_name 
        , @kw = keyword
    from search_result

    set @sql = concat('insert into result select ', @col, ' from ', @tab, ' where ', @col, ' like ''%', @kw, '%''' )
    print(@sql)

    exec (@sql)

    delete from search_result
    where table_name = @tab and column_name = @col and keyword = @kw

end
GO

select * from result
```

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you have a value `'; DROP DATABASE yourDB; --` you need to quote everything with `QUOTENAME`

Answer (score 0):

```
--initially trying to get all the column name with its respective table name, finding out if there is that particular keyword in all table,
--if yes, insert into temp table, if there aint keyword, it will insert the record too but the count of record will be zero.
--trying to make it dynamic and running it inside the loop by assigning row number to each table with different column.

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(200), COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(200), KEYWORD NVARCHAR(200), CNT INT)
DECLARE @TABLE NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @TABLE_ID INT
SET @TABLE_ID = 1
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR (200)
DECLARE @FOR_LOOP INT
DECLARE @COLUMN NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(200)
--TOTAL NO OF RECORDS FOR LOOP 
SET @FOR_LOOP = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM SYS.tables T 
                    JOIN SYS.all_columns C ON T.object_id = C.object_id
                    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES S ON S.TABLE_NAME = T.name)
DECLARE @STRINGS NVARCHAR(200)
SET @STRINGS = '%FEC%' --------->ENTER YOUR KEYWORD HERE, TRY ONE AT A TIME 
DECLARE @COUNT INT
WHILE @TABLE_ID <= @FOR_LOOP
    BEGIN
    SET @TABLE = (SELECT CAST(TABLE_NAME AS NVARCHAR(200)) 
                    FROM
                        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY T.NAME) TABLE_ID 
                        ,S.TABLE_SCHEMA SCHEMA_NAME ,T.NAME TABLE_NAME, C.name COLUMN_NAME
                        FROM SYS.tables T 
                        JOIN SYS.all_columns C ON T.object_id = C.object_id
                        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES S ON S.TABLE_NAME = T.name)A
                    WHERE TABLE_ID = @TABLE_ID)
    SET  @TABLE_NAME = '['+@TABLE+']'
    SET @COLUMN = (SELECT CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS NVARCHAR(200))
                    FROM
                        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY T.NAME) TABLE_ID 
                        ,S.TABLE_SCHEMA SCHEMA_NAME ,T.NAME TABLE_NAME, C.name COLUMN_NAME
                        FROM SYS.tables T 
                        JOIN SYS.all_columns C ON T.object_id = C.object_id
                        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES S ON S.TABLE_NAME = T.name)A
                    WHERE TABLE_ID = @TABLE_ID)
    SET @COLUMN_NAME = '['+@COLUMN+']'
    DECLARE @EXEC NVARCHAR(200) = 'SELECT ' + @COLUMN_NAME +' FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' WHERE ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' LIKE ' + ''''+@STRINGS+''''
    --THERE MUST BE ANOTHER WAY TO REPLACE SP_EXECUTESQL FOR BETTER PERFORMANCE, AS IT WILL BE EXECUTED AS MANY TIMES AS THERE ARE RECORDS IN @FOR_LOOP 
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @EXEC
    SET @COUNT = (SELECT @@ROWCOUNT)
    IF (SELECT @@ROWCOUNT) >=1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES 
        (@TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME, @STRINGS, @COUNT)
        SET @TABLE_ID = @TABLE_ID + 1
    END
    ELSE
    --DONT KNOW WHY THIS ELSE PART IS NOT TOUCHED, WHEREAS I THINK IT SHOULD HAVE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'RECORD NOT FOUND'
    END
END
GO

--AFTER THE ABOVE BLOCK IS EXECUTED THEN TRY RUNNING BELOW ONE
SELECT *FROM #TEMP WHERE CNT>0

--THERE MAY BE MULTIPLE ERROS, MUST BE EDITED AND CAN MAKE IT AS A PROCEDURE TOO.
```